# Load a csv file into a Breeze DenseMatrix[Double]

Tags: scala, functional-programming, breeze

I have a csv file and I want to load into a Breeze DenseMatrix[Double]

This code eventually will work but I think it's not the scala way of doing things:

```
  val resource = Source.fromResource("data/houses.txt")
  val lines: Iterator[String] = resource.getLines
  val tmp = lines.toArray
  val numRows: Int = tmp.size
  val numCols: Int = tmp(0).split(",").size
  val m = DenseMatrix.zeros[Double](numRows, numCols)
  //Now do some for loops and fill the matrix
```

Is there a more elegant and functional way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

```
  val resource = Source.fromResource("data/houses.txt")
  val lines: Iterator[String] = resource.getLines
  val tmp = lines.map(l => l.split(",").map(str => str.toDouble)).toList
  val m = DenseMatrix(tmp:_*)
```

much better

Comment: I think if you use `.toSeq` instead of `.toList` when initializing `tmp`, you won't have to spread it when creating `m` (can just call it as `DenseMatrix(tmp)`)